# Debian(jessie) : Permission Denied

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, root, debian-jessie

I have a NTFS partition and I installed Debian(Jessie) I added myself to the sudoer file but I can't perform any operation in NTFS partition. Please suggest me something I installed this debian third time assuming there something I was doing wrong. Please help me solve this issue. [image: error even with root user.]

```
ajaiveersandhu@cypherpunk:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ajaiveersandhu: 

root@cypherpunk:/home/ajaiveersandhu# cd /media/ajaiveersandhu/sherLOCKED/

root@cypherpunk:/media/ajaiveersandhu/sherLOCKED# mkdir folderTest
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘folderTest’: Operation not permitted

root@cypherpunk:/media/ajaiveersandhu/sherLOCKED#
```

Comment: Look at how your device is mounted (`mount` command), sounds like it is in read-only.

Comment: It is read write mounted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to install "ntfs-3g" package. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mount point:

```
mkdir /mnt/ntfs_mnt
```

Mount your partitions:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sdaX /mnt/ntfs_mnt 
cd /mnt/ntfs_mnt
```

Replace `sdaX` with your `ntfs` partition